# Steps to submitting an app into the Google Glass Glasswear Store

Tags: google-glass

What are all of the steps to submitting an app into the Google Glass Glasswear Store?

Are there any tips other then this checklist? https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/checklist

Answer (score 2):

A few tips from conversations with fellow Glass developers at various developer gatherings:

1- Keep it simple.  The API's will continue to evolve and change. Applications that have lots of screens, complex interactions and many things going on are going to take forever to get through a review process, and even if they are approved you will have a lot of maintenance.

2- Follow the templates provided by Google where possible with limited customization. Glass apps are at the crawl, not walk or run phase in terms of user experience and expectations.  Going too far away from the default templates is going to be a headache for you as Glass evolves and probably will slow down the review process.

3- Use android screen cast or another tool to capture a video of a walkthrough of your app and then narrate it.  When you submit your Glassware include a link to the video so the reviewer can get an overview before they start testing.

4- Be responsive in how you handle the various Network and GPS modes of Glass.  Remember that there will be many times when GPS or Network are spotty or unavailable, make sure you provide info in your menus and intelligently disable actions when they can't be done.

5- Don't be creepy. Think about the privacy of the end user and the people around the user.  Don't build an app that contains content you wouldn't want to share with your parents. Don't build an app that encourages user behavior you wouldn't be comfortable seeing your parents do.

Comment: My first app has been approved for Glass **[SocialRadar for Glass](https://glass.google.com/u/0/glassware/6495196315824151224)**. Two more points: **Simple = Even Simpler** When I said simple, I should have extremely simple.  Try to build 1 or two 2 easy features. Even with that first point above in mind, I ended up killing 90% of the features in v1.  **Configuration via Web/Mobile App not in Glassware** don't try to let users adjust settings in the Glassware.  Do it all on the web or in your mobile app.